# Losing internet using docker on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, docker

Here is my issue : when running some Docker containers, I loose the internet connection on my host and that's very annoying. The first time I noticed this issue it was with a simple mySQL container but it seems to be more general than that.

Actually, this issue appears in other situations, for instance when I initiate a swarm. I also tried with other databases containers : Postgres and couchDB.

My computer runs Debian and this is a pretty new configuration, I'm on Debian since February.

I could not find other similar issue on the internet, only people that can't access internet from their containers.

Don't hesitate to ask for more details, but I don't really know what else could I tell about this issue...

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT :

1. I noticed that I have this problem only when using a wifi connection (not only at home). When using an ethernet cable, everything's fine.
2. I had DNS issue after installing Debian when using wifi. I tested different answers but I finally solved it by setting /etc/resolv.conf immutable with my own DNS servers and I had no more problems.
3. Here is what docker info command gives :

> ```
> Containers: 6
>  Running: 5
>  Paused: 0
>  Stopped: 1
> Images: 78
> Server Version: 1.13.1-cs8
> Storage Driver: overlay2
>  Backing Filesystem: extfs
>  Supports d_type: true
>  Native Overlay Diff: true
> Logging Driver: json-file
> Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
> Plugins: 
>  Volume: local
>  Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
> Swarm: inactive
> Runtimes: runc
> Default Runtime: runc
> Init Binary: docker-init
> containerd version: 6c463891b1ad274d505ae3bb738e530d1df2b3c7
> runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
> init version: 949e6fa
> Security Options:
>  seccomp
>   Profile: default
> Kernel Version: 4.9.0-5-amd64
> Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
> OSType: linux
> Architecture: x86_64
> CPUs: 4
> Total Memory: 7.683 GiB
> Name: Neptune
> ID: HDM2:5HQT:MXPR:Y7P6:ZMMZ:JQAV:UQBP:NNM3:OZ3E:OA4S:MHGH:HJI6
> Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
> Debug Mode (client): false
> Debug Mode (server): false
> Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
> Experimental: false
> Insecure Registries:
>  127.0.0.0/8
> Live Restore Enabled: false
>
> WARNING: No swap limit support
> ```

4. Here is what I get from "netstat -rn" (currently connected with an ethernet cable)
   [image: netstat-rn]
5. And what I get with "ifconfig". I'm following a cloud course, many of them have been created with different tutorials : [Link to my gist](https://gist.github.com/JonathanSamelson/ec327cd612bd0169d815da413465e45d)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74771/discussion-on-question-by-dragonsen-losing-internet-using-docker-on-debian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default route is blocked when one of your containers creates a new route for the virtual network device

```
Destination Gateway     Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0 U     0   0      0    veth8835bcf
0.0.0.0     192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG    0   0      0    wlp2s0
```